# I want to go to url after installing chrome extension using chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to go to url just after installing chrome extension using `"chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener"`. But when i reinstall chrome extension nothing happens.

```
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    if (details.reason == "install") { 
        window.location= "html/ide.html";
    }
});
```

Can you help me guys?

Comment: See chrome.tabs.create, and the extensions architecture documentation.

Comment: Yes. It is working.Thank you